# Error: Can't resolve '@agm/core/services/google-maps-types'

Tags: angular

Angular Advanced google Markers

Error: Can't resolve '@agm/core/services/google-maps-types'

Error: Can't resolve '@agm/core/services/google-maps-types'
Angular Advanced google Markers

Error: Can't resolve '@agm/core/services/google-maps-types'

Error: Can't resolve '@agm/core/services/google-maps-types'

Comment: have you try **npm install**